# Composer - Multiple Dependencies Issue

Tags: composer-php

I have three separate projects (say P1, P2 and P3) each with composer setup.

P1 requires part of P2 and P2 requires part of P3, which is in-turn causing composer within P1 to force me to require P3. Is there a way to remove this dependency as none of the code in P3 is needed by P1? Other than deleting it outside of composer.

I tried setting P3 as `require-dev` within the P1 composer file and then setting the `--no-dev` flag when `composer install/update` is run, but it is still adding the vendor, I imagine because of the requirement for P2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot circumvent that P3 is appearing in the vendor directory of P1. That's how composer works.

It might be that the P2 parts that are used by P1 do not use anything that is inside P3, but that does not matter. As long as P2 states that it needs P3 to work, any project requiring P2 will also include P3.

I wonder why you are stating that you are forced to require P3. The only reason that would be true is if you also name the repositories that have your code, because you do not want to publish them via packagist.org.

But this is only half the truth. You do not have to require P3 - you only have to state all the repositories that contain all code that is eventually required.

If you want to get rid of including huge lists of private repositories with your library modules, I'd suggest you have a look at [Satis](https://github.com/composer/satis). This is a script that can create a package list of all your repositories, and then you'd only have to name the location of the created package.json file, and not every repository you might use. You have to think of a way to add new repositories to Satis, though - but you'd need to do it only once, and only there.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. They are indeed all private projects loaded via git and making them public is not an option. We have to require all projects as currently we have to load repositories via dev-master as composer does not support the tag naming convention we had previously incorporated into the projects ('vX.Y.Z-releasename').

Comment: Composer does support `vX.Y.Z` as tag name, you'd simply have to drop that `-releasename` suffix, because that is used for stuff like `alpha`, `beta`, or `RC` tagging of almost release ready versions.